# Cannot export python script output into the same csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


class GetFeeds(object):

  def main(self):
     self.malc0de()
     self.malwaredomainlist()

  def malc0de(self):
     url=requests.get('http://malc0de.com/rss/')
     feed=url.content
     soup=BeautifulSoup(feed,'html.parser')

     with open("feeds_123.csv", "w") as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
         for link in soup.find_all('item'):
           desc = link.find('description').contents 
           formatted_desc = desc[0].split(",") 
           formatted_desc_contents = [cont.split(":")[1] for cont in formatted_desc] 
           print formatted_desc_contents
           writer.writerow(formatted_desc_contents)   

  def malwaredomainlist(self):
    url=requests.get('http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/mdl.xml')
    feed2=url.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(feed2,'html.parser')
    ##print soup.prettify()
    with open("feeds_123.csv", "w") as b:
      writer = csv.writer(b, delimiter=";")
      for link in soup.find_all('item'):
        desc = link.find('description').contents 
        formatted_desc = desc[0].split(",") 
        formatted_desc_contents = [cont.split(":")[1] for cont in formatted_desc]
        print formatted_desc_contents
        writer.writerow(formatted_desc_contents)      

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    o = GetFeeds()
    o.main()
```

Currently, I am trying to export the information from both mac0de and malwaredomainlist to the same file called feeds_123.csv however, the csv file only shows malwaredomainlist items instead of showing both. I tried extracting it into 2 different files it works. May I know how can I solve this error and extract into the same file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in "a" mode instead of "w" ,"a" means append and will add new content to the previous. "w" will clean the file and write over whatever was there.